# Cleaning a list of dictionaries of lists, dicts, and tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that can contain more dictionaries, lists, or tuples. I have no way of knowing which key will have one of these objects as a value.

I am trying to remove all the mentioned above objects from the dicts but keeping anything else. Whilst at this I also have a key "list" that exists in every dictionary. I need to join this up into a string with a '-' delimiter.

I have this code and it works fine. I've been using Python3 a year now and want to know whether this is the most pythonic way to do this? I can't find much info on removing objects by types from other objects with a Google!

```
test_list = [{'val1': 'a', 'val2': 'b', 'dict': {'a': 'b'}, 'list': ['a', 'b'], 'tuple': ('a', 'b')},
             {'val66': 'a', 'val65': 'b', 'dict22': {'a': 'b'}, 'list': ['a', 'b'], 'tuple22': ('a', 'b')}]

for obj in test_list:
    x = obj
    x['list_path'] = "-".join(str(v) for v in obj['list'])
    x = {k: v for k, v in x.items() if not (isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, tuple))}
    print(x)
```

Output (which is correct):

```
{'val1': 'a', 'val2': 'b', 'list_path': 'a-b'}
{'val66': 'a', 'val65': 'b', 'list_path': 'a-b'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things I would change:

1. It doesn't make any sense to first name something `obj` to only then rename  it as `x` the next line. Maybe you thought you were copying? The first change (regarding `list_path`) actually modifies the original object.
2. `isinstance` accepts a tuple of classes to test for.

So I'd do the following (which doesn't modify the originals):

```
for x in test_list:
    filtered_x = {k: v for k, v in x.items()
                  if not isinstance(v, (dict, list, tuple))}
    filtered_x['list_path'] = "-".join(map(str, x['list']))
    print(filtered_x)
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking I was copying, but have read up on that now and realised my mistake. Thanks for this. Had no idea "isinstance" could take a tuple. Appreciated.